# Checking to make sure I understand the English in this math problem.

Tags: calculus

> Let $g$ be a function given by $g\left(t\right) = 100 + 20 \sin \left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right) + 10 \cos \left(\frac{\pi t}{6}\right)$ For $0\leq t \leq 8$, is $g$ decreasing most rapidly when $ t =$.
>
> The answer should be 2.017.

I am confused about the *decreasing most rapidly*, does it mean

A. when the 1st derivative is equal to zero,

B. When the 2nd derivative is equal to zero,

I understand that I need to take the derivative. Unsure upon which one.  I know that the first derivative is velocity and the second is acceleration, if the starting fuction is a position function and differentatie in reguards to time.

**My work**

$g^{\prime\prime}\left(t\right) = -5\,\sin \left( 1/2\,\pi \,t \right) {\pi }^{2}-{\frac {5}{18}}\,\cos  \left( 1/6\,\pi \,t \right) {\pi }^{2}$

$t=0$ at  2.017406169, 4.017973737, 5.964620094

I made a graph of the 2nd derivative (red) and the 3rd derivative (blue)
[image: 2nd derivative is red, 3rd derivative is blue]

The change that would be most rapid at the maximum of the graph in blue, which is the 3rd derivative of $g(t)$

Comment: For the sake of clarity: The first derivative of a position function with respect to time is velocity and the second derivative is acceleration. The original function must be position (of some object) as a function of time and the derivatives must be taken with respect to time for those to be true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Decreasing most rapidly* means that $g'$ is the most negative. You can set $g''=0$ to work this out.

Comment: thanks, my English has points of discontunity in the relm of Mathematical questions.

Comment: Alternatively, think of the graph: the function is decreasing where the slope of the tangent is negative. Where is the (negative) slope steepest?